# RDP freezes as soon as you click connect while on VPN using native RDP, works fine with older RDCMan 2.7 app

Tags: vpn, rdp, remote, desktop

This started yesterday for no reason I can figure.

Some VPN users can get in if they use the FQDN, but most just freeze with short, fqdn or IP.

I did notice if they are using Remote Desktop Connection Manger 2.7, they can connect no issue.

So I'm thinking it's some protocol used by the native RDP client.

I've tried every fix I can find, but they all seem to be for when it says "Securing Connection" after credentials are entered, and we don't even get to initializing.

Stuff I've tried includes disabling UDP, copying RDP cert from the server down to the desktop, and others.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by installing a previous version of Pulse Secure Client, and appears to be fixed also in the newest release.